# S3 for Rails API endpoint - is it necessary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

A mobile iOS team wants an endpoint that they can send a username, a user ranking, and either an image related to that user or an array of images if the user has a gif or animation related to them. Then they will ping that endpoint in order to render these images on another page in their mobile app.

I decided to build this in Rails as a prototype. At first I thought I would need S3 in order to store the images, but now I'm not so sure. Can't I use the built-in database within my Rails app, since my Rails app won't be rendering any of the images? What are the advantages of using S3 in this case? Is S3 necessary?

Comment: If you don't need to store the actual images but instead just need to keep the url for them you don't need S3 and can store directly in the database.  If they're sending actual image files over, you'll need to save them in S3 since Heroku's ephimeral file system doesn't persist beyond dyno restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prototyping purposes, no, S3 isn't needed. You can store the images locally in the filesystem or even in DB, though, I'd say you should start with Postgres right away, because it has an array type you can use for the images table.

However, if you are making this an actual feature of a product, yes, consider S3 very seriously. Actually, something else you might want to look into is CloudFront, because it'll allow you to build a CDN and fetching images will be faster on the user side. Locality is significant portion of a fast UI, especially if images are a big part of it.

Comment: Thanks, I researched CloudFront and I think I'm going to move forward with that instead. I appreciate the input and the redirection!